# How to date stamp last Sunday's date

Tags: excel, vba, date, timestamp, date-math

I'm looking to have a couple of dates stamped onto the spreadsheet on opening.

My current script is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Automate start time on opening
    With Worksheets("Time Recording Estimate")
        If IsEmpty(.Range("B4")) Then .Range("B4").Value = "Start"
    End With
End Sub
```

I now wish to also add a stamp for the last Sunday, hoping it can look something like the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Automate start time on opening
    With Worksheets("Time Recording Estimate")
        If IsEmpty(.Range("B4")) Then 
            .Range("B4").Value = "Start"
            .Range("V3").Value = Now() - Weekday(Now()) + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not sure which part of the formula is wrong and is failing to go through.

Much appreciated for any assistance offered.

Comment: So, what's going wrong? Are you getting an error?  It's good that you included your code - and it's also a good idea to minimize it to the part that's the problem, when possble. (ie, if it's just *miscalculating*, then you only need to include the formula.)  More info on that at: [mcve]

Comment: @ashleedawg, I'm getting a highlight on the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` line... and the script won't run at all...

Comment: it's not giving you an error?

Comment: @ashleedawg, no, not a physical error message.

Comment: when it stops on will the yellow highlighted line (that a break in code), what happens when you push F5 (to continue running the macro)

Comment: @ashleedawg, it worked... I've left out the `Else` at the end of the 2 commands... thanks so much for your time and helping me through this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165382/discussion-between-kitarika-and-ashleedawg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is missing an `End If`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Automate start time on opening
    With Worksheets("Time Recording Estimate")
        If IsEmpty(.Range("B4")) Then
            .Range("B4").Value = "Start"
            .Range("V3").Value = Now() - Weekday(Now()) + 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Once I added that (and changed the worksheet name to one that I actually have), it ran properly: if cell `B4` is empty then then it puts "Start" in cell `B4` and Sunday's date (today in this case, since it's Sunday) in cell `V3`.

I'd suggest that you [always] add this line to the top of any module:

```
Option Explicit
```

This will "force" proper declaration & usage of variables, objects,  properties, etc, and will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Also, you should **compile** the code, so you can see where problem lie.  [Here is a quick overview](https://www.devhut.net/2014/03/26/how-to-compile-vba-code/) of the process.